# Is it possible to track the quantity of clicks I have on my store?

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, custom-reports

I need to develop a **report module** on my store and I need to **track the quantity of clicks** the site have.

is it possible :

- to get the quantity of clicks
- And/or the quantity of clicks on a given time

Answer (score 0):

if you want it for analytics purpose you can use [hotjat](https://www.hotjar.com/)
free service.

it has some useful tools like heat maps and recording each user activity (including mouse tracking)

Comment: I need to get the times a product was clicked on my store, only that.
And I need to know if magento have a native way of doing that, if not, it's ok.